# how to register and use multiple interactive push categories with ios 8

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, interactive

Hello i successfully created a single interactive push set but when i tried to register for multiple set it only register the last settings and the previously registered ones just overwritten.

My question is how can i create multiple interactive push with different identifiers where i can provoke any of them when i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the setWithObjects method on NSSet to include both of your categories in one set object:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:yesNoButtonBackground, acceptDeclineBackground];
```

Then you only need to call registerUserNotificationSettings once:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                                                      categories:set]];
```